# Work with Date Time in VC++ 2005

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I have a question: How to work with Date Time Type in VC++. I search many times and only found a solution:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);   // get time now
struct tm * now = localtime(&t);
```

But I don't know how to set a Date with a specify value, example:

```
oDay = new DateTime("5, 6, 10, 5, 6, 2005");
```

I want to build a code that set a date with a specified value and check this value is valid or not. Anyone plz help me. Thank for all support!

Comment: Are you writing C or C++? What is this `DateTime`? Your code, or something else?

Comment: I use Visual C++ 2005, written in C or C++ is all accept, I only need the code that set a date, time from specified value and check it valid or not. Thank

Comment: Do you want to know how to work with a `time_t` or do you want to implement your own "DateTime" class? (BTW: your string format is non-standard, to say the least. Check out [the ISO standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).)

Comment: Any class or function that can check valid date input can accept, if you know any function or class could do this, plz tell me, thank

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`COleDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38wh24td%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class.

The [`ParseDateTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/37t16xc9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function converts date-time strings in a variety of formats into `COleDateTime` - returning `false` if the string is not valid.

You can create a `COleDateTime` containing a specific date-time simply like this:

```
COleDateTime oDay(2005, 6, 5, 10, 6, 5);
```

Comment: Dear MiMo, I use COleDateTime and get this error: **1>d:\vc 2005\q7_nguyenquochoangvi\q7_nguyenquochoangvi\q7.3.cpp(20) : error C2065: 'COleDateTime' : undeclared identifier**
Which library I must include to use this class?, thank

Comment: You need to include `atlcomtime.h`